# GitHub GraphQl api v4 return "Cannot query field repository on type Query"

Tags: android, github, graphql, apollo

I am trying to use GitHub GraphQl Api V4 to Query Data

```
query {
  repository(owner:"octocat", name:"Hello-World") {
    issues(last:20, states:CLOSED) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          url
          labels(first:5) {
            edges {
              node {
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this query is working as well on Git-Hub query [explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/) 
But when I tried it using insomnia or Apollo library return **"Cannot query field \"repository\" on type \"Query\"."**

Comment: Sounds like you're not connected to the right endpoint. Double check and make sure you're making requests to `https://api.github.com/graphql`

Comment: @DanielRearden I check it and I am sure I'm connecting to the same URL

Comment: can you share your schema (typedef) ?

Comment: The following curl request works just fine. You should update your question with the relevant code (client config and how you're actually sending the query). Otherwise, there's not enough to go on. `curl -H 'Authorization: bearer YOUR_API_TOKEN' -X POST -d '{"query": "{ repository(owner: \"octocat\", name: \"Hello-World\") { issues(last: 20, states: CLOSED) { edges { node { title url labels(first: 5) { edges { node { name } } } } } } } }"}' https://api.github.com/graphql`

Answer (score 0):

```
{
search(query: "repo:octocat/Hello-World type:issue is:CLOSED"
first: 20
type: ISSUE) {
  issueCount
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Issue {
          title
          createdAt
          labels(first:5) {
            edges {
              node {
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).